# Updating MOTD for SSH

Tags: puppet

I have the following code in my manifests/site.pp

```
file { "/etc/motd":
  mode => '0664',
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  content => 'THE MESSAGE I WANT TO APPEAR'
}
```

When I ssh into the server I get no message, even though the /etc/motd file exists.  If I then edit that file and save it, even if I make no changes to it, exit ssh and reconnect the MOTD appears.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: A wild guess, but is it because you are unaware of the default 30 minute period between Puppet runs, i.e. did you login, check the file, wait a bit, Puppet runs, then it got updated?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this environment but I'm starting it with vagrant so not sure if this is still applicable?

Comment: I would start by inspecting the log (/var/log/messages by default on most Linux) - does that tell you when Puppet changed the file?

Comment: Nah nothing in there.  Very strange.

Comment: Well Puppet does work. :) You'll need to provide more info.